Adjusting pH of non-aqueous solution
I’m planning to use Tetrahydrofuran (THF) to dehydrate biological tissues expressing fluorescent proteins, followed by delipidation with dichloromethane. Since fluorescent proteins are sensitive to acidic conditions, I aim to adjust the pH of THF to around 9.0, using triethylamine as a base. However, because THF is non-aqueous, standard pH meters are unreliable for this adjustment. Is there an effective way to consistently control the pH of THF, or perhaps a reliable alternative method? My main goal is to achieve dehydration without quenching the fluorescence of the proteins.

pH of non-aqueous solvents (and even more so, of aprotic ones like THF) is an ephemeral abstraction indeed. What does it even mean?

You’re right—that’s why I’m looking for a reliable alternative method if possible. My goal is practical: in pure THF or when biological tissues introduce small amounts of water into THF, I want to create a ‘gentle’ environment that preserves the integrity of fluorescent proteins.

@user165966, you say your goal is practical. Can't you just try then? Add a little triethylamine (such as 0.1 %) and see if it works. That is not such an uncommon strategy which is used for example in column chromatography on silica with acid labile compounds. Or do you have any way to estimate acidic amounts in your sample?

pH measurements by glass electrodes in non-aqueous system are almost undefined. While I have unfortunately seen PhD level researchers dipping the pH electrodes in aqueous methanol or acetonitrile to adjust the pH of such solutions with acids or bases, but as you rightly pointed out, the displayed number on the meter is nothing but an unreliable number. It also dehydrates the glass electrode and THF may damage the plastic casing.
For practical purposes, you can use a pH indicator which is soluble in THF/Water solvent system and you can make a calibration curve yourself on a UV-Vis spectrophotometer. Add different amounts of base and monitor how pH changes the absorbance spectrum of the indicator. You will have to search the literature. Even fluorescent probes can be tried.
Alternatively, make a pure aqueous solution of water / TEA. Add known amounts of triethylamine to each solution of the same volume. Measure the pH and prepare a pH calibration curve (pH vs. conc. of TEA or vol of TEA). Use this chart to quote the pH when you add the same amount to TEA to the THF/water solution. This graph can be provided in the Supporting File of the paper.
